# VBA Macro to Delete Empty Lines in Word Tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I been struggling with a word macro that deletes Empty lines where a "$" exists. The code below works but only for the selected table, how can I have the code loop through the entire document and delete empty lines from all pages.

[image: Document]

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()
Dim i       As Long
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 3 And Left(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text, 1) = "$" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are only looking into tables in each worksheet?

Comment: Yes, But doesn't have to be table as long as it deletes any empty line where a dollar sign exist.

Answer (score 3):

This is not tested on the same data-set as OP has since it is not provided.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST() 


Dim tbl As Table
Dim mDoc As Document
Dim oRow As Row

Set mDoc = ActiveDocument


    For Each tbl in mDoc.Tables

        For Each oRow In tbl.Rows

                 If Len(oRow.Cells(2).Range.Text) = 3 And _
                    Left(oRow.Cells(2).Range.Text, 1) = "$" Then 

                        oRow.Delete 

                 End If 
              Next oRow 
    Next tbl

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Masoud. It is failing for Compile Error.

Comment: @user7675421 now it's working. Don't refer to word documents as workbooks to avoid from this kind of confusions. I was doing it for excel workbooks.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I tried it doesn't fail but it doesn't delete any empty lines. Thanks

Comment: @user7675421 they are not empty as you describe them. They have 3 characters and the left one is dollar-sign. Correct? Can you provide a screenshot of what you have and what is the desired outcome?

Comment: I added a screen shot in the question. If one of the lines is empty meaning has the dollar sign but no numbers next to the dollar sign then I want the entire row deleted.

Comment: @user7675421 It works totally fine. I dunno what do you mean. Check your rows for extra spaces after dollar-sign.

Comment: Hi Masoud, I apologize for not being clear from the beginning.. I have a mail merge document and after I merge the template the data, I end up with a large word document (Merged document). Within that document, there are multiple lines where the dollar sign exists. My goal is: If No numbers (Let's ignore spaces) are next to the dollar sign (Within five spaces to the right), then delete that whole line (example: If no amount for the base amount line then delete entire base amount line from the word document.). I hope that makes sense.. Thanks!

Comment: @user7675421 is it a line or a row in a table? You should seriously read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other links at the bottom of this.

Comment: Row in table..Thanks

Comment: @user7675421, then my code works fine. For that to consider spaces search "how to check if a character is a number in vba" and add a condition to the if-statement. SO is not a code writing community. This is not hard to accomplish at all. Good luck.